# How to do two trigger (insert / update / delete) for the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

As I can do two trigger for the same table, I have to do an update for when you modify a person's data (user and mail), but also I have in the same table, to modify the status of a person (active or inactive) , Make two updates, one for when you change the data of that user and another only when you change the status but at the time of making the modification of the status system I also activated the first trigger (to change the user and mail) Can I do in that case? I am using mysql triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER Usuarios_AModificar AFTER UPDATE ON usuarios FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (
    accion, 
    fecha,
    cedUsuario,
    nombreUsuario,
    tipoUsuario,
    usuarioNuevo,
    correoNuevo,
    correoViejo,
    usuarioNuevo,
    usuarioViejo) 
  VALUES (
    'Modifico',
    NOW(),
    @identificador,
    @identificador2,
    @identificador3,
    NEW.usuario,
    old.usuario,
    NEW.correo,
    old.correo)

CREATE TRIGGER User_AModifyestatus AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (
    accion,
    fecha,
    cedUsuario,
    nombreUsuario,
    tipoUsuario,
    estatusNuevo,
    estatusViejo)
  VALUES (
    'Modifico',
    NOW(),
    @identificador,
    @identificador2,
    @identificador3,
    NEW.estatus,
    old.estatus)
```

Comment: I have some trouble understanding your question, but from the example it is not immediately apparent to me why you would need two separate triggers for this. Just have one trigger which stores the OLD and NEW values for each of the three columns, regardless of which one(s) of them have actually changed? If you have more columns, but the trigger should only do something when one of these three has changed, you need some conditional logic inside the trigger (look into how to use [IF within triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html))

Comment: In the first trigger the data of that person user and mail and in the second it did it doing for when it modified the status but when it modified the status the other activates at the same time

Comment: Well then like I said you need some conditional logic in your triggers. `IF OLD.estatus <> NEW.estatus THEN ...`. But again, your example inserts seem identical except probably leaving some fields `NULL` in the destination table. Having these `NULL` fields may or may not be worth the added trouble of more complicated triggers. Also your `Usuarios_AModificar` insert has a mismatch between column list length (10) and insert value list length (9).

Comment: What @Thernys says is completely right. You don't need two triggers for the same table. A trigger is created for a DML operation so no matter what it do when you define it as an update trigger it will ALWAYS be called (both of then on your case). That's why you need just one trigger with a conditional logic to check which field was updated. Thernys, you understand it right, you should add an answer showing how to do so.